# Select top X from table where SUM(column) <= @variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select the top n number of rows where the sum of a column is less than or equal to a number i pass in as a variable.

TableX:

```
Col1  Col2
1     10
2     10
3     5
4     20
```

So basically i'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE SUM(Col2) <= 25
```

And I would be expecting the result:

```
Col1  Col2
1     10
2     10
3     5
```

Comment: Is this possible when all 4 rows don't have a common value in Col1? Because, based on your example, this can also be a valid result:

Col1    Col2
3       5
4       20

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are looking for something similar to a running-total?  If this is the case, are you sorting by col1 or col2?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to a sql server at this time to test a complete solution but... in mysql this seems to do exactly what you want, and it should also do it for T-SQL if I am not mistaken.

```
SELECT A.Col1, A.Col2, SUM(B.Col2) AS CumulativeCol2
FROM TableX A
INNER JOIN TableX B ON B.Col1 <= A.Col1
GROUP BY A.Col1
HAVING SUM(B.Col2) <= 25
```

returns:

```
Col1    Col2    CumulativeCol2
1       10      10
2       10      20
3       5       25
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for

Comment: First, thanks for the help here.  I have to apologize but it's been years since I've touched SQL, hence my reaching out here.  I tried your suggestion however it doesnt seem to be summing Col2.  Instead its just returning all the records for which Col2 <= 25

Comment: +1 Why the down vote?? If you are going to down vote someone be a man and post your reason why, otherwise you are just a sniveling coward!

Comment: @MarkKram: because the first couple seconds before I edited I had a wrong answer and that's how it works.

Comment: @Kris, I am not commenting on your post, I was commenting on the coward who downvoted you but I got your back on this one. Anyone who wishes to downvote someone should be required to explain why they felt they needed to do so.

Comment: @MarkKram I know and your attitude is welcomed and appreciated! but I knew I was going to get down voted for having an incomplete/inaccurate answer until I implemented and tested the thing so that's just what I get for trying to be first (and failing that even :/)

Comment: The purpose of this board should be to encourage others to participate but rather most person here seem to take joy in down voting others and attempting to embarrass them. There are too many internet tough guys on this board.

Comment: @MarkKram: I prefer to look at the bright side, I got an interesting problem to solve and I did. everything else is bonus ;)

Comment: I agree with you, there are a lot of brilliant people on this board but there are also a lot more "little" people here as well who take pride in finding errors in user's posts rather than trying to help them. They have a very elitist attitude. I try to call them on it when I witness it here and on other boards.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @table as table(Col1 int, Col2 int)
insert into @table values (1, 10)
insert into @table values (2, 10)
insert into @table values (3, 5)
insert into @table values (4, 20)



 ;with TableWithIndex(Row, Col1, Col2)
 as
 (
   select row_number() over(order by Col1) Row, Col1, Col2
   from @table   
 ),
 ColTable(Row, Col1, Col2, Col2Sum)
 as (
   select Row, Col1, Col2, Col2 Col2Sum
   from TableWithIndex
   where Row = 1 and Col2 <= 25
   union all
   select ti.Row, ti.Col1, ti.Col2, ti.Col2 + Col2Sum
   from TableWithIndex ti
   inner join ColTable ct on ct.Row + 1 = ti.Row   
   where ti.Col2 + Col2Sum <= 25
 )
 select Col1, Col2
 from ColTable
 option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: What if first row (Row = 1) has Col2 > 25 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need (including proof of concept):

```
declare @t table(Col1 int, Col2 int)

insert into @t values
(1, 10),
(2, 10),
(3, 5),
(4, 20),
(5, 3)

select * from
(
    select t1.Col1, t1.Col2, SUM(t2.Col2) as runningtotal
    from @t t1
    inner join @t t2 on t1.Col1 >= t2.Col1
    group by t1.Col1, t1.Col2
) ss
where runningtotal <= 25
```

Comment: What if you have 100000 + 1 groups ? And, what if Col1 has duplicate values ?

Comment: top 100000 there only to make possible order by inside a sub-select (which is need here). You can set it to a higher value

Comment: It should, however, come with a caveat about it being half a cross product.  100 rows will yield 5,050 rows before the GROUP BY.  1000 rows will yield 500,500 rows before the group by.  A million record table will blow your roof off.

Comment: @Dems You are right. However, although possible, it's improbable that a real case scenario will happen. You will most likely filter your original data before applying this approach.

Comment: @Adrian I don't understand why is there "top 100... order by" in the subquery, why not just to sort outside "where runningtotal <= 25 order by col1".

Comment: @Alexey The problem is that you have to ensure order while calculating the running total. The filtering (`<=25`) happens *after* you have the running total. SQL Server does not "show love" when you have `order by ` inside a CTE, unless you have a `TOP` clause (or other couple of constructs that right now I do not remember)

Comment: @Adrian I don't see any reason to sort groups after sums are already calculated, sorting in the subquery doesn't influence the filtering either. If to move sorting to the outside, the result is the same for the data in the answer (maybe that's the data that doesn't show difference). Anyway, that's just my thoughts, if you sure the sorting is needed in the subquery, let it be.

Comment: @Alexey sorting **is not** done **after** the running total is calculated. The sums are calculated within the sub query and the order by must be there to **ensure** the running total order. Data might be showing OK because it's being display as it was recorded in the DB. But that does not guarantee order. Of course, you can test it yourself (try storing the data in a different order or try changing the order by clause, result will change).

Comment: @Adrian Reversed the data - no difference:http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1968/running-total-subquery-sorting  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1967/running-total-outside-sorting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4362/discussion-between-adrian-and-alexey)

Comment: In the end, `order by` was not needed. @Downvoter, would you care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Please do not confuse the values from TestDataID `identity(1,1)` column with `RowNumber` values​​. There is no link between this values.

This solution is using recursive CTEs:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData
(
     TestDataID INT IDENTITY(2,2) PRIMARY KEY
    ,ProductID  INT NOT NULL
    ,SalesQty   INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT  TestData 
SELECT  1, 10
UNION ALL
SELECT  1, 10
UNION ALL
SELECT  1, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT  1, 11

UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 20
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 10

UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 27
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 3;

DECLARE @param INT = 25;

CREATE TABLE #Results --or table variable
(
     TestDataID INT NOT NULL
    ,ProductID  INT NOT NULL
    ,SalesQty   INT NOT NULL
    ,RowNumber  INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY(RowNumber, ProductID)
);
INSERT  #Results(TestDataID, ProductID, SalesQty, RowNumber)
SELECT  a.TestDataID, a.ProductID, a.SalesQty,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ProductID ORDER BY a.TestDataID) RowNumber
FROM    TestData a;

;WITH CteRecursive
AS
(
    SELECT   a.ProductID
            ,a.RowNumber
            ,a.TestDataID
            ,a.SalesQty
            ,a.SalesQty AS RunningTotal
    FROM    #Results a
    WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
    AND     a.SalesQty <= @param
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   crt.ProductID
            ,crt.RowNumber
            ,crt.TestDataID
            ,crt.SalesQty 
            ,prev.RunningTotal + crt.SalesQty
    FROM    #Results crt
    INNER JOIN CteRecursive prev ON prev.ProductID = crt.ProductID
    AND     prev.RowNumber + 1 = crt.RowNumber
    WHERE   prev.RunningTotal + crt.SalesQty <= @param
)
SELECT   a.TestDataID
        ,a.ProductID
        ,a.SalesQty

        ,a.RunningTotal
FROM    CteRecursive a
ORDER BY a.ProductID, a.RowNumber;

DROP TABLE #Results;
DROP TABLE TestData;
```

Results:

```
TestDataID  ProductID   SalesQty    RunningTotal
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
2           1           10          10
4           1           10          20
6           1           5           25
10          2           20          20
12          2           2           22
```

Comment: Common Table Extension were introduced in SQL 2005, so if the OP tries your query (or mine), he will be very confused. It's not our fault, though..

Comment: True. But, I don't see any references regarding SQL Server version. I assume it is min. 2005. For SQL Server 2000 (2005, 2008) can be used the "quirky update" method described by Jeff Moden [on sqlservercentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) or cursors.